# Export data as double with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to export selected data  from Excel sheet  to simple txt file.
Column A must be exported as INT, column B as String, column C as INT , column D as String, column E as Double (on export must save data as double format - 35.50, 30.00, 0.00)
You can take a look to attached picture for more info.
Column A.B,C,D are fine, but I can not force column E values to to be extracted to txt file as double (in excel this column is look fine - 35.00 for example, but when is extracted to txt file is 35 )
This is my VBA script:

```
Rem Attribute VBA_ModuleType=VBADocumentModule
Option VBASupport 1
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  
    Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer

    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\rezultat.txt"
    Set rng = Selection

    Open myFile For Output As #1

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

            If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                Write #1, cellValue
            Else
                Write #1, cellValue,
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Close #1 
End Sub
```

and that is result in my txt file:

```
1,"1144641",1,"NAME-STRING VALUE",350.5
```

Everythink is just fine, except last value: must be 350.50
You can take a look at the screenshot in the attachment

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Format the value to display 2 decimal places when writing it to the file

```
    If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
        Write #1, Format(cellValue, "#.00")
        'or Format(cellValue, "Standard")
    Else
        Write #1, cellValue,
    End If
```

This is because, by default, only the value/content of the cell is being written, not the cell formatting.

---

If you wish to avoid writing the value as a string with quotes then, rather than iterating rows and columns, you could construct a single string to write for each row. For example,

```
cellValues = rng.Cells(i, 1).Value & ",""" & rng.Cells(i, 2).Value & """," _ 
    & ... & Format(rng.Cells(i, 5), "#.00")
```

Doubling-up on the quotes "" is necessary to embed a quote.

Comment: You could also investigate Excel's data export options, rather than iterating rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks, but in this way its export the last column as a string: "350.50",  I want to be exported as  number 350.50, without quotes.....

Comment: @MiroslavKostadinov I have added to my answer.